# For loop with if to detect variable change in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a double for loop with a if condition inside to check if the variable change from 0 to 1.
The data are stored in a dataframe (the data I want to check are FAULT flag recorded by test bench).
I want to write a little tool that detect any change in the column of FAULT flag (column 164 to 211) and display the result after like an overview.

I have written the following code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def get_csv():  # Import data from a csv file
    global df
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV file", '*.csv')])
    df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path, sep=';', header=0, na_values=['#NV', ' '], decimal=',', encoding='cp1252')
    return df


def loop_column():
    # fault = []
    name_list = []
    name_list2 = []
    for j in range(164, 212):  # cycle through column 165 to 211 of dataframe
        # fault.append(j)
        for i in range(len(df)):  # cycle through all row of selected columns of the dataframe
            data = df.iloc[i, j]
            col_name = df.columns[j]
        if data == 1:
            name_list.append(col_name)
            col_name = df.columns[j]
            print(col_name + " = 1")
        else:
            col_name = df.columns[j]
            name_list2.append(col_name)
            print(col_name + " = 0")
    print(name_list)
    print(name_list2)
    

get_csv()
loop_column()
root.mainloop()
```

But it doesn't do what I want. It only detects a FAULT if the last row of one column is 1. If any other row is at 1 (for example the n-1 or at the beginning of the column) the loop_column function return 0 instead of going in the if data == 1: condition

I guess my problem is because I'm using a standard integer variable instead of a list to store the different value of the dataframe column. And the variable is getting overwritten during loop iteration.
But I can clearly see that the print() message inside the if is seeing the 1 value because I see a message "my DF column name = 1" so I know it is there (the 1 inside the column)

Comment: are the if statements supposed to be outside the second for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that @Rashan Arshad has identified the issue exactly. In the second `for` loop, the program will assign `data = df.iloc[i,j]` for each value of `i`, but it will not check if `data` is equal to 1 until it has exited the `for` loop. This is why you only flag this column if the last entry is 1.

The fix is indentation of the `if-else` conditional.

However, to address the comment below, we actually want to refactor slightly, so that we only have to iterate through each column, rather than every column and row:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def get_csv():  # Import data from a csv file
    global df
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV file", '*.csv')])
    df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path, sep=';', header=0, na_values=['#NV', ' '], decimal=',', encoding='cp1252')
    return df


def loop_column():
    # fault = []
    name_list = []
    name_list2 = []
    for j in range(164, 212):  # cycle through column 165 to 211 of dataframe
        # fault.append(j)
        col_name = df.columns[j]
        if 1 in df[col_name].values:
            name_list.append(col_name)
            print(col_name + " = 1")
        else:
            name_list2.append(col_name)
            print(col_name + " = 0")
    print(name_list)
    print(name_list2)
    

get_csv()
loop_column()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes it is working better but now it is appending the column name more than once (each time it detects a 1 in the column). What I wanted the function to output is one column name if one or more 1 are detected in the columns. I did that indentation modification yesterday but didn't realized that it was working fine because I'm getting so much print message it's hard to see what's going on. I guess I have to change the code inside the if to only output the name of each column that have a 1 in them.

Comment: @gamer388 I see better what you are going for now. See the updates in the question for a simpler way to check if the value is in the column one or more times. The key is the 1 in df[col_name].values conditional, which checks every value in the column.

Comment: Ok I found out on internet that there is a method to remove duplicate data from a list. list(dict.fromkeys(name_list)) So I created a new list using this method. And it does the job like I want. Edit yes your solution work too and is better because it remove the loop that scan all rows (in my case I had 30k lines)